# MS Access - Query design help

Tags: ms-access

I need to design a query that finds "duplicates" in MS Access table. They are not true duplicates, in that every field is not identical, but it is highly unlikely that a patient would be seen twice within 60 days, so 2 records in that timespan are likely duplicates.

The relevant columns in the table are:
id integer autoincrement
patientid text
proceduredate date/time

I want to produce a list of patientid where the proceduredate is within 60 days of each other. I was able to find a list of all "duplicates" with the following query:

SELECT * FROM tblProcedures
WHERE patientid = ANY
(SELECT tblProcedures.patientid
FROM tblProcedures
GROUP BY tblProcedures.patientid
HAVING COUNT(tblProcedures.patientid) > 1)
ORDER BY tblProcedures.patientid,  tblProcedures.proceduredate DESC

But I'm not sure how to limit the results to records involving the same patientid where the proceduredate is within 60 days of a previous procedure.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to join the table to itself:

```
Select * 
From tblProcedures  As P1
    Inner Join tblProcedures  As P2
        On P2.PatientId = P1.PatientId
                And P2.Id <> P1.Id
Where Abs(DateDiff("d", P1.ProcedureDate, P2.ProcedureDate)) <= 60
Order By P1.PatientId, P1.ProcedureDate Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblProcedures P1
LEFT JOIN tblProcedures P2
    ON P1.patientid = P2.patientid
    AND P1.proceduredate < P2.proceduredate
    AND DateDiff("d", P1.proceduredate, P2.Proceduredate) <= 60
WHERE P2.patientid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY P1.patientid, P1.proceduredate DESC
```